# Copy file to root of Xcode project when building

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics

I am trying to implement Google Analytics (GA) in my iOS apps. I have two different targets that have different tracking-ids for GA. GA requires a `GoogleService-Info.plist` (cannot be renamed) file to be placed in the root of the app folder structure. This file contains the tracking-id. However, since I have two different targets I need to have two different tracking-ids.

I cannot have two file named to files with the same name with different targets.

So, is there a way to either copy another file into the root in the build process. Have tried this and similar but does not seem to work:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

**The script:**

```
PLIST_FILE="CustomGoogleService-Info.plist"
PLIST_PATH="${PROJECT_DIR}/path/To/Plist/Here/${PLIST_FILE}"
cp "${PLIST_PATH}" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

Instructions:

- Add this script to the end of your `Build Phases`
- Change name `CustomGoogleService-Info.plist` to your own
- Change `pathToPlistHere` to the correct path where `CustomGoogleService-Info.plist` is located (starting from your project directory)
- You should not have `GoogleService-Info.plist` file in your project - the script will create it for you.
- Grab a coffee while it is running

You may be interested in reading [Apple's Xcode Build Setting Reference](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/itcaec37c2a6)

**Alternatively:**
You could have 2 files with the name `GoogleService-Info.plist`, but keep each in separate directory. Then you could add each to the corresponding target. Without any script.

Comment: Great tip the alternative way!

Comment: The non-alternative way is superior, imo. It also will work if you have one target, but multiple configurations (e.g. dev, beta, prod).

Comment: how can you add build script for only a specific scheme / configuration?

Comment: @AlexW, he may be thought about something like 
`if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]; then .... fi`
ps: ahoj.

Comment: here the file is not getting copied. I still see the old file.
tried removing, force copy as well. but not working any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I did correctly all along, however `Destination` should be set to `Wrapper` and subpath empty. No need to have them in the target either.

This one explained the Destination options: [xcode copy files build phase - what do the destination options mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156490/xcode-copy-files-build-phase-what-do-the-destination-options-mean-exactly)